# Boolean value into sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

What is the best and most optimized way for inserting Boolean value into SQL Server in C sharp?
I've used an Int16 parameter and pass it via stored procedure, but I think it is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

You may map a boolean to sql directly as

```
bool boolVar = true; 
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", boolVar);
```

Or explicitley mention it as a bit type

```
bool boolVar = true;
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Bit);
parameter.Value = boolVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL column type should be bit, hence 0 or 1.

you should use int in your c# code, that's fine

Comment: Why "you should use int"? Rather than just `bool`? Should use a parameter of datatype `SqlDbType.Bit` and that maps to boolean.

Comment: no need of int. as said by @MartinSmith, you can map boolean to sql-server